# What do people mean when they say that Bitcoin are "unconfiscateable"?

Tags: security, private-key, privacy, wallet-security, data-security

So all my Bitcoin are on an encrypted wallet.dat inside a VeraCrypted USB memstick inside a fireproof safe.

While this might stop random a burglar, how does it stop the government from confiscating them? Or any targeted attack?

What if I wake up tomorrow tied to my bed, with a bunch of gangsters or cops (no real difference) around me. They go:

> Okay, Sonny. Instructions to locate your Bitcoins. Now.

And one of them loads a gun and points it at my head.

Let's assume that I'm the most hardened, badass Bitcoin owner on the planet (which I'm definitely not) and I actually reply:

> Go ahead! Pump me full of led, you bastards! I'm going down with my Bitcoins!

Now, they look at each other, nod in a sinister manner, and one of them gets a little glass cage from a backpack. As I'm wondering what is going to happen, and why they aren't killing me, they place a gigantic, nasty spider on my chest, still in the cage, and say:

> Thought you'd get away that easily, huh? We know your biggest fear, you stupid slave! You have ten seconds to tell us the correct instructions to how to get to your private keys or we'll open the door and allow this aggressive, eight-legged freak to nest in your mouth.

There is no way in Hell that I wouldn't instantly start crying my eyes out and scream:

> GOD NO! PLEASE! I'LL TELL YOU! IT'S IN THE SAFE IN THAT WARDROBE BEHIND ME! COMBINATION 4 x 25 RIGHT, 3 x 73 LEFT, 2 x 23 RIGHT, 1 x 91 LEFT! THE KEY TO THE SAFE IS LOCATED UNDERNEATH THE BED! THE WALLET.DAT IS ON A VERACRYPT-ENCRYPTED USB STICK INSIDE. PASSPHRASE BLABLABLA! THE WALLET.DAT IS ENCRYPTED WITH THE PASSPHRASE BLABLABLA! YOU FIND A SERIES OF CLUES IN A RANDOM TEXT FILE CALLED SHOPPING.TXT! ANY INSTANCE OF "WOLF" MEANS "X999DL%¤(/(SSSSSFJ1389u2/(D"! MY FIRST CAT'S NAME WAS FLUFFY! MY SECRET LOVE IS ANGELICA! THE GAME I'M TALKING ABOUT TOWARD THE END IS DOOM FOR ATARI JAGUAR 64! I SWEAR THIS IS THE TRUTH! PLEASE PUT THE MONSTER AWAY RIGHT NOW!!!!!

Even somebody who isn't extremely scared of spiders like I am (which they would easily find out) would find the idea of having a spider crawl into your mouth and on your face extremely unpleasant. Of course, they could just start bashing my knees in or cut off my fingers, or threaten to kill my pet, or child, or other loved one, etc. Such people do exist.

In fact, they could simply tell me that unless I comply, they will simply imprison me under terrible conditions until I spill the beans. Would you want to sit isolated in a small room and eat whatever crap they feel like serving you to keep me alive for the rest of your life just for the sake of not having to give up your Bitcoin? I'd say that would be even more horrible than being poor again.

I don't understand why some people keep repeating this mantra that Bitcoin is somehow unconfiscatable. Haven't I more than proven my point with this frightening scenario?